# show user control when button_click event

Tags: c#, webusercontrol

I want to display user control when button_click event.

The user contol declartion is

```
<div id="divloginUControl" runat="server">
   <td></td>
      <td>
        <LUC:LoginLoader ID="loginUserControl" runat="server" />
      </td>
 </div>
```

I have tried with

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        loginUserControl.Visible = false;
    }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loginUserControl.Visible = true;

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        ScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(Button1);
        string result = asset.UserLogin(txtloginid.Text, txtpassword.Text);
        if (Convert.ToInt32(result) == 1)
        {
            Session["uname"] = txtloginid.Text;
            Server.Transfer("CreatedInventory.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            pwdinfo.Text = "Please enter correct password";
            txtpassword.Focus();
        }
    }
```

but it is not working, please give some suggetions

Comment: How not working? Where did you set this value?

Comment: More code professional

Comment: Did you try debugging ?

Comment: yes, paste your code, don;t re-type. We need to see the context.

Comment: @nphx i have writeen this in button_click event

Comment: @huMptyduMpty yes, i have tried with debugging, but no use

Comment: @tariq <div id="divloginUControl" runat="server">
                                          <td></td>
                                          <td>
                                               <LUC:LoginLoader ID="loginUserControl" runat="server" />
                                          </td>
                                      </div> and i use that usercontrol in button_click event

Comment: bhasker just edit your question and paste this code details there

Comment: post your click event also

Comment: protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loginUserControl.Visible = true;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        ScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(Button1);
        string result = asset.UserLogin(txtloginid.Text, txtpassword.Text);
        if (Convert.ToInt32(result) == 1)
        {
            Session["uname"] = txtloginid.Text;
            Server.Transfer("CreatedInventory.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            pwdinfo.Text = "Please enter correct password";
            txtpassword.Focus();
        }
    }

Comment: Can you confirm that you don't set this 'divloginUControl' visible false somewhere?

Comment: nope, i didn't declared

Comment: is there any need to write any code in usercontrol.ascx.cs

Comment: you are using multithreading right, i guess that its getting visible false in some other thread, check that

Comment: Do mark as answer in case this helps in solving the issue, will help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh got it try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostback)
    {
        loginUserControl.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

**Update** : you are using multithreading right, i guess that its getting visible false in some other thread, check that

Comment: I have tried with that too.. same problem

Comment: what does the breakpoint reveal?

Comment: it is giving that true, while i check with breakpoint. but it is not displaying control

Comment: Can you confirm that you don't set this 'divloginUControl' visible false somewhere?